# set [null] = null? (or "Burninate [null]?")

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

In my opinion, the [null](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/null) tag is not helpful for anyone. Even if this tag matches the content of the question, it might be a bit too specific.

I'm not a programmer. What are your opinions on burninating the tag?

---

The [null](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/null) tag has four tagged questions:

- [Reducing cyclomatic complexity in a simple string concatenation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40941/reducing-cyclomatic-complexity-in-a-simple-string-concatenation)
- [A custom Java collection which doesn't support nulls](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30688/a-custom-java-collection-which-doesnt-support-nulls)
- [Handling nil: Trying to avoid #try](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28610/handling-nil-trying-to-avoid-try)
- [Null Object pattern with simple class hierarchy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24869/null-object-pattern-with-simple-class-hierarchy)

(Thanks for the title suggestion by [lol.upvote](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13606142#13606142))

Comment: Or do we set it to `undefined`?

Answer (score 12):

Considering that Tony Hoare calls the invention of the null pointer a ["billion dollar mistake"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#cite_ref-6), I think it's a very worthy concern for software developers, on par with [exception-handling](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exception-handling), [comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comments), or [naming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming).  Also, the treatment of NULLs in SQL is tricky.  If a developer has a question about the handling of nulls, then it wouldn't be unreasonable to tag that concern.

Comment: the problem with this argumentation is that these tags do only provide information that should've been provided as text in the question in the first place. That's for **all** of the tags you mention. Concerns about the code under review are question text. Tags are to categorize what the code does to allow subject experts to find applicable questions easier.

Answer (score 1):

This tag does not seem to provide any particular value to questions, and doesn't always mean the same thing on different questions according to the tag description.  Additionally, I'm not too sure [exception-handling](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exception-handling), [comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comments), and [naming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) are that great of tags either (see other answer).